# PHP & FTP synchronization freezing all site

Tags: php, ftp

I have page, in which are a lot of sites, with their source codes, i need to synchronize them to ftp, one site, has its own ftp. Im using FTPsync class. It is working very good, files are going to FTP but problem is when i clicking on "Push files to FTP", then my main site is freezed until ftp synchronization process is done, can anyone say to me, what is the problem ? why that is happening, and maybe offer how can i solve this. Thanks.

If FTPsync class source code is needed, let me know i will add it here.

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough details. What is "hangs"? Is it hanging from one machine only? At what point does it hang? See [session\_start hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333209/session-start-hangs) for exmample. If you're going to show code, show the generic outlines. The FTPSync class is the less interesting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're performing the FTP syncing process within the same request, then yes your page will take a very long while to load and might interfere with other requests as well.

The suggested way of doing this is usually to make a job queue, in which you can use a storage system (database, etc) or a message queue to queue the jobs, and write another script to perform the syncing.

If you want an easier way to solve this, you can just

1. Use `ignore_user_abort()` and `flush` to cut away the user connection and continue the syncing in the background
2. Embed a frame within the page which is performing the action and show a progressbar. Then at the end of the sync do a `window.parent.location = 'done-syncing'`

For 1., here's an example:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo 'Syncing...';
ob_end_flush();
flush();

// Perform the FTP syncing here
```

For 2., it will span across multiple pages. Suppose clicking on "Push files to FTP" brings you to a page `ftp_sync_start.php`, and then the file which does the real syncing is `ftp_do_sync.php`, then here are some examples:

`ftp_sync_start.php`

```
<!-- You can put some sort of progress bar here -->
<iframe src="ftp_do_sync.php?<?php // Pass some parameters here ?>"></iframe>
```

`ftp_do_sync.php`

```
<?php
// Just do the syncing here, then at the end
echo "<script>window.parent.location = 'ftp_sync_done.php';</script>";
```

These solutions are not too scalable though.

Comment: Thank you, i will try your suggestion.