# session_start() makes page load for infinite

Tags: php, session-variables

I know there are so many similar questions but none worked for me.
Heres my server specification.

PHP Version 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

I also tried custom path for session.save_path with full permission but still its not working.

Any idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: ... do you have multible requests at the same time? Note that session_start is blocking and waits for other requests from the same user.

Comment: I think no, I am only using at the moment. But even if for multiple requests it should work. Yes I know its adding more requests in queue. But I dont think there is that much requests.

Comment: Same project is running very smooth on local and amazon ec2 linux instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session\_start hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333209/session-start-hangs)

Comment: I have checked that and its not worked for me. In fact I checked so many similar questions.

Comment: Are there any hints in apache log files /var/log/apache2/(access|error)_log ?

Comment: Nothing in log but now I used session handler and replaced with redis. So thanks to all for help :)